# Rundeck python script permissions

Tags: python, permissions, rundeck

I am new in rundeck and I am trying to execute a simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys

file = open("/home/anonymous/Documentos/pruebas.txt","w")
file.write(sys.argv[1])
file.close()
```

When I try to open the file, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied: '/home/anonymous/Documentos/pruebas.txt'
```

How does it work the permissions in rundeck, which user does it uses?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an RPM/DEB based installation: try to check the permissions fo that path for "rundeck" user/group, a good idea is set a generic path for your scripts and give permissions to Rundeck user (something like /scripts). Like all UNIX/Linux users, Rundeck user can't see another userspace like /root or /home/johndoe. If you have a WAR based installation is the same concept but with the user that launches Rundeck.